# Do Stanley Cup Champions get a replica of the cup?

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl, awards, stanley-cup

In most sports the champions of a cup get to keep it. For example NFL champions keep the Lombardi Trophy. However, the Stanley Cup is unique and NHL champions don't get to keep it forever. But do they receive a replica of it to display?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three different kinds of Stanley Cup:

- Original (used between 1892-1970 - now resides in the Vault Room at the Hockey Hall of Fame)
- Presentation (created in 1963 - presented to Stanley Cup winning teams and used for promotions)
- Replica (created in 1993 - used as a stand-in at the Hockey Hall of Fame when the Presentation Cup is not available for display)

According to this article, [22 Things You Might Not Know About the Stanley Cup](http://mentalfloss.com/article/51140/22-things-you-might-not-know-about-stanley-cup), there is a "Keeper of the Cup" who accompanies the Cup (presumably the Presentation Cup used today - as the other two are specifically used for display at the Hockey Hall of Fame) wherever it goes.

> Do Stanley Cup Champions get a replica of the cup [to display]?

No. However, the NHL grants the Stanley Cup winning team 100 days with the Cup during the off-season, accompanied by the Keeper of the Cup. In 1994-1995, the  New Jersey Devils established the tradition of giving each player on their team one day with the Cup during the 100 day time frame.

Comment: So the "Keeper of the Cup" will follow the Cup around to all of the players' homes?

Comment: @pacoverflow Yes. There's even [journal entries](http://www.hhof.com/htmlSTCjournal/exSCJ_main.shtml) dating back to 2003 capturing the players with the Cup, wherever they may go.

Comment: yeah the keeper of the cup is well known among hockey fans. He has been the keeper for many years.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do. All major sports give the winning team their own replica of the champion's trophy. There's a picture of a former Oilers (Ranford?) goalie with his 2 replicas. Their about 2 feet tall, with the team's player's names engraved on it, as is the coaches and owner. [image: picture of the replicas and other trophies won by Ranford]

Comment: "All major sports"? Not even close.

Comment: @nij The all major sports part may be wrong (though I think he's maybe on the right track, as often teams at least get a replica [such as this](http://www.bizjournals.com/pittsburgh/stories/2010/09/06/daily24.html)).  But regardless of that aspect, the image is a very important contribution to the question, as it makes it appear that replica trophies are indeed actually in play (who provides/pays for them is still important)

Comment: "Some do" is not on the same track as "all do". And as the accepted answer states, the NHL in particular does not give replicas either. This answer is just factually wrong in at least two places.

Comment: @Nij Do you have a source for that (I honestly know nothing of this topic, just trying to get it clearer for us who come in unknowing).  Even if it's just something you've heard, it would give some background to help solidify it :-)

Comment: The accepted answer states to the question, "Do ... champions get a replica of the cup [to display]?", "No".

Comment: That said, people will get a replica if they want one, even if they have to do it themselves. It's just unlikely to be *an* official replica, because there is already *The* official Replica Cup. And the NHL doesn't own the Cup either, so that is likely to create issues they'd rather avoid, given the tenuous legal ground they already stand on in terms of trademark.

Answer (score -2):

Out of the big 4 only 3 sports gets a trophy and only one. That goes to the owner. With the exception of NHL. As stated above about the cup. This why the players in all 4 sports get rings. There are no replicas awarded to players or coaches ect. 
However the players can custom order a replica from its maker or someone that specializes in sports awards. They aren't cheap. But pro sports players can afford it. The most expensive trophy other than the cup is the WS trophy. Ben Z now with Cubs got one for the KC WS. Not sure if he got another for the Cubs. Several Denver players also had Super Bowl Trophies done. They are exsact to the real deal but made of Nickel not sterling silver like the originals. But they have to pay for it. The league does not award them nor gives them to players so who ever said they did they are wrong trust me I know.  Hope that helps.

Comment: It is better to add official sources to confir what you have written