# Which watches are given as gifts to ice hockey players in the world cup?

Tags: ice-hockey

During the ice hockey world championship, the best player of each team receives a gift - it seems like it is a watch.

I am curious - what kind of watch is it (brand / model)?
Since one of sponsors is Tissot, I guess that might be the brand but I cannot find a model.

Comment: Why downvote? Is this question inappropriate or should be moved to another site? Please let me know.

Comment: I'd assume downvoting is because it's not sports-related.

Comment: @E.Sommer I disagree as I would consider this "gift" to be a prize for the best player of each team, and identifying the prize isn't off-topic, in my opinion.

Comment: I think this question is as much "sports-related" as other discussions about sports trophies (like Stanley Cup - https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13922/do-stanley-cup-champions-get-a-replica-of-the-cup )

Answer (score 1):

In IIHF Worlds 2017 it was Tissot.
Reference:

at time 2:09:14 you can clearly see it.